# urxvt prompt starts in the middle of screen and tmux shows gibberish when started from it

Tags: bash, virus, tmux, malware, urxvt

Lately I noticed that my terminal prompt on `urxvt` does not start on the first line when I open it, but on the middle of the screen. Also when later I execute `tmux` command to use tmux inside a urxvt window, I see some gibberish before and after the prompt.

1. This is how my `urxvt` looks like when I open it.
   [URxvt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc4bo.png)
2. This is how my `tmux` looks like when I spawn it from `urxvt`.
   [Tmux screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmIjN.png)

My OS is debian 12/kali+i3+x11+xdm.
I tried to reinstall all binaries mentioned and also replace the config with the default one. Also tried to edit config but it did not help.

My guesses are:

- Probably a backdoor is malfunctioning and throws me gibberish.
- Some third-party package ruined my configs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, seems to be duplicate of this: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/241646.
In my case changing `URxvt*geometry: 80x240+0+0` in ~/.Xresources fixed the issue.

Comment: That fixed urxvt but not tmux problem.
Thank you for helping!